# Storing User Object in Zend_Auth's Default Storage

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

Is storing an object containing the user's data in Zend_Auth's default storage secure? Why or why not?

Comment: Zend_Auth stores data in a session. So the date will be as secure as your sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend_Auth's default storage uses PHP Session. It's 'security rating' depends on server overall security.

In double words - it is `secure enough`.